# Can't find references in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I create a new projet in my global solution and add some references who are others projets in the same solution.

I have something like that in my references folder :

[image]

In the properties screen, the path is empty and can't be edit, whereas in the others projets, path is set correctly.

And of course, when I'm trying to call this lib, it's impossible to call this reference.

Comment: Try editing the csproj file and see if that reference looks different from the others.

Comment: @user2621595 Adding to roryap comment. Open the .CsProj file in Notepad or some other text editor and try to find ParalleBatchLibrary. You might notice it is being referenced or the hint is different.

Comment: Your project is referencing an assembly that doesn't exist. Either it isn't registered in the GAC or the path is wrong. [Troubleshooting Broken References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayds71se.aspx)

Comment: God I'm shamefull to not think about that.
The framework reference was set in 4.5 and not in 4.5.1. It solve the problem. Thx !

Comment: Sometimes this can be a problem with the solutions configuration as well. Sometimes you need to select Any CPU or MIxed Platforms and make sure stuff is checked properly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting it from references and adding it again, maybe you changed a name or moved the project to a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your target framework is same for the your two projects.
RightClick in your projects>> Properieties>> target FrameWork.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28UC6.jpg)